# Realm - change listener call

Tags: android, realm

I have a question. When is called RealmChangeListener? After finishing of transaction? Or immediately after operation.

I have a relationship 1:N User:Task. I want to watch changes of all tasks.

When I use:

```
realmUser.getTasks().add(realmTask)
```

Than task was correctly added for task, but listener was not called.

I update is to this solution:

```
realmTask = r.copyToRealm(realmTask)
realmUser.getTasks().add(realmTask)
```

And listener works, but question is when is called?

Comment: When you `commitTransaction()`. If the transaction is on a background thread, then the change listeners will be called with some delay on the UI thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends if the change listener was registered on the same thread or on a different thread.

If on the same thread, they will be triggered when you call:

- `Realm.refresh()`
- `Realm.beginTransaction()`
- `Realm.commitTransaction()`

If on a different thread, they will be triggered when that thread receives a looper event from the thread that changed the Realm. How long that takes can vary a bit as background worker thread need to calculate all changes to report before calling any listeners.

Listeners will not be triggered, if they are "empty" or if the Realm didn't change, i.e. calling `refresh()` is not guaranteed to trigger listeners if the Realm was already fully up to date.